# Powershell popup while file is being moved

Tags: powershell, popup

When my script starts it moves a file from one directory to another. After the file is completely downloaded I launch an application.
This all works, but what I would like is a popup window to appear while the file is being moved (Large files). 
When I debug my code once it hits the Move-Item Cmdlet it waits until that command is completed before it moves on. What I want to do is while the Move-Item Cmdlet is running, popup an information window.
I know how to do the popup and the Move-Item, I just don't know how to get it to work the way I want. Any ideas?
Popup code

```
 #pop up window letting mechanic know we are waiting for the files to be downloaded before opeing the SMT application
            $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
            $wshell.Popup("The EAFR file is still being moved to the correct directory, please wait.",0,"SMT Status",0)

#Move-Item
    $MLMoveDir = "C:\move\data\AutoUpload\"
    Move-Item -LiteralPath ($filePath) $MLMoveDir
```

Comment: Why do you want a popup?  Why not just write to the console, then write when you're finished?

Comment: Because the user is clicking on an icon to launch an application not PowerShell.

Comment: Not clear what *how to get it to work the way I want* means.  What way do you want it to work?

Comment: He wants to keep the pop-up on screen while the file is being moved. The issue is that I don't know how to close the pop-up once the move has finished. I could suggest ways to pop-up, and make the pop-up keep appearing while the move is in progress with jobs, but making it go away escapes me at the moment.

Comment: I remembered that the wscript.popup has a time-out built in, just had to utilize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use WinForms to display a *Please Wait* dialog, rather than a Popup that has to be dismissed by the user.  Something like:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 
$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Form.Controls.Add($Label)
$Label.Text = "Copying file, please wait."
$Label.AutoSize = $True
$Form.Visible = $True
$Form.Update()

#Move-Item
$MLMoveDir = "C:\move\data\AutoUpload\"
Move-Item -LiteralPath ($filePath) $MLMoveDir

#Hide popup
$Form.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you could do is start the Move-Item as a job, and then do a While((get-job "jobname").state -ne completed){do popup}. I would look something like this:

```
#Move-Item
    $MLMoveDir = "C:\move\data\AutoUpload\"
    $MoveJob = Start-Job -scriptblock {Move-Item -LiteralPath ($filePath) $MLMoveDir}
#Show Popup
    While($movejob.state -ne "Completed"){
        $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
        $wshell.Popup("The EAFR file is still being moved to the correct directory, please wait.",1,"SMT Status",0)
    }
```

That way the popup shows for 1 second, and if the move is still happening it shows it again. I don't know that it would even appear to disappear/re-show so it would likely be seamless.

Comment: I like this @TheMadTechnician, I just need to find out if I can upgrade to PowerShell 3.0 on the Machines that this is going to run on.